# Dependency injection in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, interface

I am trying to create an instance of a class in a controller. But, I am not able to do it.

Controller code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("connection")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        return new OkObjectResult(new MyClass().ShowData(firstName, lastName));
    }
```

Class code:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    void SomeMethod();
}

public class MyClass
{
    private readonly ISomeInterface _someInterface;

    public MyClass(ISomeInterface someInterface)
    {
        _someInterface = someInterface;
    }

    public Task<bool> ShowData(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        // some logic
        if (firstName == "Ram")
        {
            ClassOne obj1 = new ClassOne();
            obj1.DoPlus();
        } else if (firstName == "Sam")
        {
            ClassTwo obj1 = new ClassTwo();
            obj1.DoPlus();
        }
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

Another interface

```
public interface IClassOneTwo
{ 
  void DoPlus();
}

public class ClassOne : IClassOneTwo
{ 
  public void DoPlus()
  { }
}

public class ClassTwo : IClassOneTwo
{ 
  public void DoPlus()
  { }
}
```

How I can inject `ISomeInterface` into the controller? Also, How I can decouple instances of ClassOne and ClassTwo? I want to register IClassOneTwo interface and based on IF/ELSE condition, I want to get an instance of ClassOne OR ClassTwo.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: It's still not clear. `How I can inject ISomeInterface into the controller?` That's in the answer below. `How I can decouple instances of ClassOne and ClassTwo?` I have no idea what that means.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @KiddoDeveloper I would suggest you read up on strategy pattern

Comment: @Nkosi. I know about strategy pattern. So, isn't there any other way to do it. Like we register interface in the DI container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For completeness sake, you should abstract `MyClass` behind an interface.

For example:

```cs
public interface IMyClass
{
    Task<bool> ShowData(string firstName, string lastName);
}
```

And have `MyClass` implement it:

```cs
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    private readonly ISomeInterface _someInterface;
    public MyClass(ISomeInterface someInterface)
    {
        _someInterface = someInterface;
    }
    public Task<bool> ShowData(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        // some logic

        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

Then in your `Startup.cs` class, in the `ConfigureServices` method, you should register it:

```
services.AddTransient<IMyClass, MyClass>();
```

You should also register `ISomeInterface`:

```
services.AddTransient<ISomeInterface, SomeOtherClass>();
```

Then, in your controller, you should inject the services you want via the constructor:

```cs
public sealed class MyController : ControllerBase
    
    private readonly IMyClass _myClass;

    public MyController(IMyClass myClass)
    {
        _myClass = myClass;
    }

    [HttpPost, Route("connection")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething(
        [FromQuery]string firstName, [FromQuery]string lastName)
    {
        return Ok(await _myClass.ShowData(firstName, lastName));
    }
}
```

### Edited To Add...

The OP is asking how to make `MyClass` more-or-less a utility that can perform an operation using `ISomeInterface`. So, you still want to register `ISomeInterface` to the pipeline:

```
services.AddTransient<ISomeInterface, SomeOtherClass>();
```

You can switch `MyClass` back to how you have it.

Inject `ISomeInterface` in to your controller as shown above, then just pass it to `MyClass`:

```cs
public sealed class MyController : ControllerBase
    
    private readonly ISomeInterface _someOtherClass;

    public MyController(ISomeInterface someOtherClass)
    {
        _someOtherClass = someOtherClass;
    }

    [HttpPost, Route("connection")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething(
        [FromQuery]string firstName, [FromQuery]string lastName)
    {
        return Ok(await new MyClass(_someOtherClass)
                .ShowData(firstName, lastName));
    }
}
```

### Edited to Add (again)...

So I think we got to the bottom of what OP wants. They want to inject two services that share the same interface. There are many ways to do this. I'll stick to one that I have used in the past.

First thing, define a delegate:

```
public delegate IClassOneTwo MyServiceResolver(string key);
```

Then in your `Startup.cs`, in the `ConfigureServices` method, register:

```
services.AddTransient<ClassOne>();
services.AddTransient<ClassTwo>();
```

Keep in mind we don't use the interface when registering. That is important.

Now we create another service that can resolve which one you want:

```cs
services.AddTransient<MyServiceResolver>(serviceProvider => key =>
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case "Ram":
            return serviceProvider.GetService<ClassOne>();
        case "Sam":
            return serviceProvider.GetService<ClassTwo>();
        default:
            return null; // or throw an exception
    }
});
```

Then, in whatever service you decide to inject in to (for simplicity's sake, I will use the controller):

```cs
public sealed class MyController : ControllerBase
    
    private readonly MyServiceResolver _serviceResolver;

    public MyController(MyServiceResolver serviceResolver)
    {
        _serviceResolver = serviceResolver;
    }

    [HttpPost, Route("connection")]
    public IActionResult DoSomething(
        [FromQuery]string firstName, [FromQuery]string lastName)
    {
        _serviceResolver(firstName).DoPlus();

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Now, your service will be resolved at runtime.

Comment: just for clarity, they only needed to inject someinterface,  they could then have passed it in the constructor to myclass.   However, as you have in your code, the most likely desired behavior is both being injected

Comment: Thank you @Andy. I have a problem with with IMyClass. I have a two classes which is inherited from IMyClass i.e. ClassOne and ClassTwo. Based on a name condition argument 'firstName', I need to create an instance of ClassOne OR ClassTwo. How I can do it?

Comment: you don't need to do it through an interface, you can just inject ClassOne and ClassTwo

Comment: So you mean. I should directly create an instance of ClassOne OR ClassTwo ?

Comment: @KiddoDeveloper -- how do you know which one you need? What's the logic? I will update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: In ShowData method of MyClass, there is a if condition. Example: if(firstName == "Ram") { ClassOne obj1 = new ClassOne }, Else if (firstName == "Sam") { ClassTwo obj2 = new ClassTwo}

Comment: I think that you misunderstood my question. I have updated my question. Can you please look at it

Comment: @KiddoDeveloper -- I changed my answer, but I'm not following what you are saying with ClassOne and ClassTwo. Do you want to inject them?

Comment: I have updated my question again. My code is working fine but as we shouldn't create instance in any class like I am creating of ClassOne and ClassTwo. So, I want to register IClassOneTwo interface and based on IF/ELSE condition, I want to get instance of ClassOne OR ClassTwo.

Comment: @KiddoDeveloper -- so you want to register two objects, both using the same interface in to your DI pipeline?

Comment: Yes Sir. Thank you :)

Comment: @KiddoDeveloper -- OK -- we can do that, but it's not going to be pretty. At the end of the day you can't inject 2 services with the same interface. You have to create two distinct interfaces. I will put up an answer that may get you to where you want to be.

Comment: you can't inject 2 services with the same interface: So, If I have a ICar interface, I shouldn't have multiple classes (Honda, Audi, BMW) with ICar interface. Should I write different interface like IHonda, IAudi, IBMW. I am in the same situation.

Comment: @KiddoDeveloper -- updated answer. If that doesn't do it, then maybe someone will come along and get it right. I have to head to bed.

Comment: Thank you Andy for your time and efforts